# Date format in Oracle- fetching Date of certain range

Tags: oracle, date, birt, spagobi

I have a date table in my db in Oracle. When I run a query I get the date format as '01-05-2015' but when I run a similar query in BIRT, I get the date format as '01-MAY-2015 12:00 AM'. How can I get the date format in dd/mm/yyy by keeping the data type of date field as date.

here is sample of my database.

```
EQ_DT
05-07-2015
06-06-2015
15-02-2015
19-09-2015
28-12-2015
```

also my query is :

```
select to_date(to_char(to_date(enquiry_dt,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YY'),'DD/MM/YY') as q from xxcus.XXACL_SALES_ENQ_DATAMART where to_date(to_char(to_date(enquiry_dt,'DD/MM/YY'),'DD/MM/YY'),'DD/MM/YY')>'21-06-2012' order by q
```

I am getting error of NOT A VALID Month also

Comment: I think you should seek solution in birt date formatting .. sql and oracle are not the issue here..

Answer (score 1):

If enquiry_dt is already a date column, why are you trying to convert it to date (and then to char and to date again)?

```
SELECT to_char(enquiry_dt, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS q
FROM   xxcus.xxacl_sales_enq_datamart
WHERE  enquiry_dt > to_date('21-06-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
ORDER  BY enquiry_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

In birt, where you place the field on the report, set the field type to date. Then in properties for that field , go to format date time, and finally specify the date formatting you want for that field .

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to *always* use pass date parameters as strings to BIRT, using a known date format. This is for report parameters as well as for DataSet parameters.

Then, inside the query, I convert to date like this:

```
with params as
( select to_date(pi_start_date_str, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as start_date_incl,
         to_date(pi_end_date_str, 'DD.MM.YYYY') + 1 as end_date_excl
  from dual
)
select whatever
from my_table, params
where ( my_table.event_date >= params.start_date_incl 
        and
        my_table.end_date < params.start_date_excl
      )
```

This works independent of the time of day.
This way, e.g. to select all events for january 2016, I could pass the query parameters '01.01.2016' and '31.01.2016' (I'm using german date format here).